# Create an app with web interface on mobile OS using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, webview, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to create cross-platform a mobile app with a Web-based interface using Xamarin.Forms?

The idea is to create a mobile app using C# Xamarin code-behind and web-based UI.

I know that it is possible to call Java code from javascript using Android WebView. The question is there are any common techniques for binding Xamarin.Forms WebView (or other web view controls) and C# code-behind for cross-platform development (Android, IOS and Windows)?

Comment: It really depends on how many platform-specific features you need to access which can't be directly used in the PCL -- if it's a lot, then you might end up using the DependencyService fairly often. I think a better elaboration of what you're trying to do with your project would be of help, here.

Comment: I didn't get the point of the comment. To get straight: I've got a UI - HTML pages with javascript, and I want to call C# (Xamarin cross-platform) code behind directly from javascript (like calling java code from javascript on android only). So the question is - is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got instructions of building WebView with possibility to call C# functions.

First common explanation is on [official guide for xamarin.forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/).
And here is [GitHub project](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HybridWebView) for such WebViews.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.  Create a custom renderer for your webview, add a function to the Navigating event handler, and in that event check the url for your indicator:

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public CustomWebView()
    {
        Navigating += OnShouldLoad;
    }

    private void OnShouldLoad(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Url.StartsWith("runcode") || !e.Url.Contains(":"))
            return;
        var urlInfo = e.Url.Split(':');
        switch (urlInfo[1])
        {
```

This assumes the javascript will send a url in the form "runcode:*Command*" where Command indicates the action that you want to take.